# skipping lines while reading from csv file in java

Tags: java, string, csv

```
private static List<Book> readDataFromCSV(String fileName) {    
    List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
    Path pathToFile = Paths.get(fileName);

    // create an instance of BufferedReader
    // using try with resource, Java 7 feature to close resources
    try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile,
            StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)) {
        // read the first line from the text file
        String line = br.readLine();

        // loop until all lines are read
        while ((line  = br.readLine())!= null) {
            // use string.split to load a string array with the values from
            // each line of
            // the file, using a comma as the delimiter
            String[] attributes = line.split("\\|");

            Book book = createBook(attributes);

            // adding book into ArrayList
            books.add(book);

            // read next line before looping
            // if end of file reached, line would be null
            line = br.readLine();
        }

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return books;
}


private static Book createBook(String[] metadata) { 
    String name = metadata[0];  
    String author = metadata[1]; // create and return book of this metadata 
    return new Book(name, price, author); 
}
```

The above code skips every second line from text file (a csv file).
It gives data of alternate lines and it uses Java 7 syntax.
Please provide some suggestion what is wrong or how to improve it.

Comment: The [BufferedReader readline specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) says that the call is followed by a linefeed. The second readline() call results in the missing lines.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `br.readLine()` inside the `while` condition i.e.

```
// read the first line from the text file
String line = br.readLine();
// loop until all lines are read
while (line != null)
{
    ...
    // read next line before looping
    // if end of file reached, line would be null
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

Comment: Since he wants to read 1 line of every 2 lines so I don't think this is going to work.

Comment: @LocTruong as I understood it that is the actual problem and that OP wants to read every line.

Comment: yes it works. but when i do SOP(name), it start printing from middle of  file.

Answer (score 2):

You have called the br.readLine() function twice in the loop.

One is in the condition:

`while((line = br.readLine()) != null)`

and the second one is at end of the loop.

So the loop is actually reading a line at the end, and then reading the next line at the beginning without processing it. To avoid this, you can remove the br.readLine at the end of the loop.

```
while ((line  = br.readLine())!= null)
                {

                    // use string.split to load a string array with the values from
                    // each line of
                    // the file, using a comma as the delimiter
                   String[] attributes = line.split("\\|");

                   Book book = createBook(attributes);

                   // adding book into ArrayList
                   books.add(book);
               }
```

If you did not get it, the condition:

`while((line = br.readLine()) != null)`

is actually doing the following:

storing the returned value of br.readLine() in the variable line,

and then checking the condition. Therefore, you do not need to call it again in the loop.